# Displaying images in Atom feed using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-feed

I'm trying to iterate over each articles' pictures in an Atom feed. I have the following code which renders an Atom feed just fine, but am not sure if these are the correct image tags.

Any advice on what the optimal setup for this is would be amazing.

This renders the XML below; index.atom.builder:

```rails
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "posts"
  feed.updated @articles.maximum(:updated_at)

  @articles.each do |article|
    feed.entry(article) do |entry|
      entry.title article.title
      entry.content(article.body, type: 'html')
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name article.author

        if article.pictures.any?
          article.pictures.each do |pic|
            entry.logo image_tag pic.photo.url(:large)
          end
        end 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

XML output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>tag:HEROKU APP:/articles</id>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="herokuapp.com"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"herokuapp.com/articles.atom"/>
  <title>posts</title>
  <updated>2012-09-10T16:42:27Z</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>tag:herokuapp.com,2005:Article/9</id>
    <published>2012-09-10T16:42:27Z</published>
    <updated>2012-09-10T16:42:27Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="herokuapp.com/articles/9-test-lorum"/>
    <title>Test Lorum</title>
    <content type="html">wddsadasdsadasd</content>
    <logo>&lt;img alt="Alaska" src="/assets/articles/12/large/alaska.jpg?1347295345" /&gt;</logo>
    <author>
      <name>Andy</name>
    </author>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, we did solve it however we too a different approach to putting the image in an atom feed. As our feed was being imported into google currents and currents automatically puts any images included like the method below into a slideshow (which we didnt want) we decided to just include the img tag of the image in the body content of our article/post or whatever. Not really a solution but it worked better for our needs.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, it's what I'm doing now too.

Answer (score 1):

Could be wrong, but you might just need an `html_safe` call on it.

```
 entry.logo image_tag(pic.photo.url(:large)).html_safe
```

Comment: hmmm, still doesn't seem to be working, its atom very specific about having the images in a 2:1 ratio? and if they aren't in that format they dont get displayed?

Comment: Was more or less noticing how the image tag rendered with escaped html tags. In terms of the atom spec, i really have no idea, sorry.